# Register services with kazoo python and use for service discovery

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I am trying to register some services and use it as a service discovery using **Apache Zookeeper** and implementing it in python using the **Kazoo** library. Having a hard time to figure out how to trigger the API call from zookeeper and redirect the HTTP request to the required API

Suppose I have a basic website running on my localhost and I want to register some of its APIs using kazoo into zookeeper and reach them when necessary

some routes of my websites are :

127.0.0.1:8000/register

127.0.0.1:8000/login

127.0.0.1:8000/login/auth

127.0.0.1:8000/home

127.0.0.1:8000/jasmine/Oauth/run

```
import logging
import time
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
from kazoo.client import KazooState

zk = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk.start()

zk.ensure_path("127.0.0.1:8000/")

if zk.exists("127.0.0.1:8000/"):
    print('found')

data, stat = zk.get("127.0.0.1:8000/")

print("Version: %s, data: %s" % (stat.version, data.decode("utf-8")))

children = zk.get_children("127.0.0.1:8000/")

print("There are %s children with names %s" % (len(children), children))

zk.stop()
```

I am not able to register any services mentioned above and also tried another [library](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zc.zk#zc-zk-zookeeper) "zc.zk". It gives me an error

> File
>   "/home/**root**/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zc/zk/**init**.py",
>   line 259
>       print 'extra path not trimmed:', cpath

Can you please point me in the right direction where should I start registering services and get the data in return. And use my python script as an orchestrator to my incoming requests

Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance